# Identify h264 profile and level from profile-level-id in sdp?

Tags: sip, h.264, sdp

In a SIP video call, the receiver of the video stream respond with the capabilities of its decoder.

The parameter which defines that is the `profile-level-id`. Here is an example value of the profile-level-id parameter: 428014

RFC 6184 defined that as

> A base16 [7] (hexadecimal) representation of the following
>            three bytes in the sequence parameter set NAL unit is specified
>            in [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Profiles): 1) profile_idc, 2) a byte herein referred to as
>            profile-iop, composed of the values of constraint_set0_flag,
>            constraint_set1_flag, constraint_set2_flag,
>            constraint_set3_flag, constraint_set4_flag,
>            constraint_set5_flag, and reserved_zero_2bits in bit-
>            significance order, starting from the most-significant bit, and
>            3) level_idc.

According to that, the following parameters from the example value can be identified:

- profile_idc 42
- profile-iop 82
- level-idc 14

How to relate those numbers to the [profiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Profiles) and [levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Levels) defined for h264?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For such things you should read actual [H.264 spec](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.264-201304-S/en) not Wikipedia. Using it you can parse your example as

- profile_idc 0x42 == 66 so it is Baseline profile
- profile-iop 0x80 mean constraint_set0_flag=1 (so it is Constrained Baseline profile) and others 0
- level-idc 0x14 == 20 so it is Level 2.0

So result is Constrained Baseline profile Level 2.0

Comment: The 'Recommendation H.264, "Advanced video coding for generic audiovisual services"' section 7.4.2.1.1' states `constraint_set0_flag equal to 1 indicates that the coded video sequence obeys all constraints specified in
subclause A.2.1. constraint_set0_flag equal to 0 indicates that the coded video sequence may or may not obey all
constraints specified in subclause A.2.1.`. Where A.2.1 defines the Baseline profile. How did you decode that? Please answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494168/h264-profile-iop-explained

Comment: I'm looking at 2012 version of ISO/IEC 14496 10 and section A.2.1.1 defines Constrained Baseline profile as "Conformance of a bitstream to the Constrained Baseline profile is indicated by profile_idc being equal to 66 with constraint_set1_flag being equal to 1."  I believe constraint_set0_flag=1 is true for just Baseline profile.  Thus the example in the answer is just Baseline

Comment: Also see here for discussion about the different constraint bits: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494168/h264-profile-iop-explained

Answer (score 2):

Refer to following table from RFC 6184: Table 5. Combinations of profile_idc and profile-iop representing the same sub-profile corresponding to the full set of coding tools supported by one profile. In the following, x may be either 0 or 1, while the profile names are indicated as follows. CB: Constrained Baseline profile, B: Baseline profile, M: Main profile, E: Extended profile, H: High profile, H10: High 10 profile, H42: High 4:2:2 profile, H44: High 4:4:4 Predictive profile, H10I: High 10 Intra profile, H42I: High 4:2:2 Intra profile, H44I: High 4:4:4 Intra profile, and C44I: CAVLC 4:4:4 Intra profile.

```
      Profile     profile_idc        profile-iop
                  (hexadecimal)      (binary)

      CB          42 (B)             x1xx0000
         same as: 4D (M)             1xxx0000
         same as: 58 (E)             11xx0000
      B           42 (B)             x0xx0000
         same as: 58 (E)             10xx0000
      M           4D (M)             0x0x0000
      E           58                 00xx0000
      H           64                 00000000
      H10         6E                 00000000
      H42         7A                 00000000
      H44         F4                 00000000
      H10I        6E                 00010000
      H42I        7A                 00010000
      H44I        F4                 00010000
      C44I        2C                 00010000
```

It is Baseline Profile Level 2.0.